# JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<' In angular

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json, ajax

**This is my angular code. form submit code. When click on submit button. `JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'` this error will showing. empty records will save on the DB. I added html code and PHP server side  code also for this.**

```
 $scope.submitForm = function() {

    $http({
      method  : 'POST',
      url     : 'http://localhost/youtubewebservice/checkOutt.php',
      data    : $scope.user,
      dataType: 'json',
      headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
     })  
      .success(function(data) {
        if (data.errors) {
          $scope.errorinputFName = data.errors.inputFName;
          $scope.errorinputLName = data.errors.inputLName;
        } 
      });  
    };
```

**Html code**

```
<form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm()">
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="inputFName" class="form-control" ng-model="user.inputFName">
    <span ng-show="errorName">{{errorName}}</span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="inputLName" class="form-control" ng-model="user.inputLName">
    <span ng-show="errorEmail">{{errorEmail}}</span>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      <div id="sendmessageresponse"></div>
</form>
```

**PHP code **

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8");

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$inputFName = mysql_real_escape_string($data->inputFName);
$inputLName = mysql_real_escape_string($data->inputLName);

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('look4com_lk', $con);

$qry_em = 'select count(*) as cnt from checkout where chkID ="' . $chkID . '"';
$qry_res = mysql_query($qry_em);
$res = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry_res);


if ($res['cnt'] == 0) {
    $qry = 'INSERT INTO checkout (inputFName,inputLName) values ("' . $inputFName . '","' . $inputLName . '")';
    $qry_res = mysql_query($qry);
    if ($qry_res) {
        $arr = array('msg' => "User Created Successfully!!!", 'error' => '');
        $jsn = json_encode($arr);
        print_r($jsn);
    } else {
        $arr = array('msg' => "", 'error' => 'Error In inserting record');
        $jsn = json_encode($arr);
        print_r($jsn);
    }
} else {
    $arr = array('msg' => "", 'error' => 'User Already exists with same email');
    $jsn = json_encode($arr);
    print_r($jsn);
}
```

Comment: check what is being sent to the server via fiddler

Comment: paste the output of the json being sent.

Comment: `{"msg":"User Created Successfully!!!","error":""}`

Comment: The header of your POST request should include an indication that the transferred data is a JSON. I don't recall the exact syntax, but is something like `application_data/json`. Google on this to see how exactly it should be written. OOPS!! Just say that there, but I'm not sure it is the correct way of defining.

Comment: what is the correct way. pls can you give me some help

Comment: Which line in your code produces the JSON Parse error?

Comment: I think java script

Comment: Without the line if it hard to localize the problem. Please check your console (e.g. your Firebug console) to get the line.

Comment: I checked after that hard code the data server will save. but actual data not save

Comment: @FDavidov It's `application/json`.

Answer (score 1):

This particular parse error indicates that the output is no valid JSON (duh). Since your output is formatted with `json_encode`, it should be. (Although I usually use `print_r` for arrays only ...) However ...

My experience tells me that your server produces an error / notice, which php usually outputs with some html, hence the `<`. Since you claim, that the response is clean JSON, I suggest you look at the actual responses your server sends. My assumption is, that you tested your php-script from command line (hence the `php://input`?) but a server possibly handles requests differently than you'd expect.

You can check the server's responses in the network tab of almost every decent browser, usually F12 -> network tab, then reload and/or resend the form. If you have problems solving your php-problem, add the php error message to your question or ask a new one.

As a final remark: Please avoid the `mysql_*` functions (deprecated mysql library) and either use the `mysqli_*` functions (mysqli library) or PDO. Also use prepared statements.

Comment: I changed `json_encode` and `mysqli_` but same error. I have

Comment: @DRK I have the feeling you only read the first and last paragraph. Also your comment seems  to be cut off.

Comment: second paragraph also I did. then empty record not working

Comment: @DRK Your form sends a query to the server, your server likely has an actual php error message in the response and your angularjs chokes on that. To find out what that php error message is, you have to open your form, and look at the actual response of the server with the help of your browser's developer tools. And that response is what anyone wanting to help you will need. But you don't provide that but instead write "i did, not working". Provide. More. Information.

Answer (score -1):

I found the error of this code. this code working properly. any one have any question ask. thanks

**html code**

```
<div ng-controller="ProductController">
<form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm()"> 
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="inputFName" class="form-control" ng-model="user.inputFName">
    <span ng-show="errorName">{{errorName}}</span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="inputLName" class="form-control" ng-model="user.inputLName">
    <span ng-show="errorEmail">{{errorEmail}}</span>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      <div id="sendmessageresponse"></div>
</form>
  </div>
```

**PHP code **

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$inputFName = mysql_real_escape_string($data->inputFName);
$inputLName = mysql_real_escape_string($data->inputLName);



//localhost
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('look4com_lk', $con);

$qry_em = 'select count(*) as cnt from checkout where inputFName ="' . $inputFName . '"';
$qry_res = mysql_query($qry_em);
$res = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry_res);



if ($res['cnt'] == 0) {
    $qry = 'INSERT INTO checkout (inputFName,inputLName) values ("' . $inputFName . '","' . $inputLName . '")';
    $qry_res = mysql_query($qry);
    if ($qry_res) {
        $arr = array('msg' => "User Created Successfully!!!", 'error' => '');
        $jsn = json_encode($arr);
        print_r($jsn);
    } else {
        $arr = array('msg' => "", 'error' => 'Error In inserting record');
        $jsn = json_encode($arr);
        print_r($jsn);
    }
} else {
    $arr = array('msg' => "", 'error' => 'User Already exists with same email');
    $jsn = json_encode($arr);
    print_r($jsn);
}
```

**controller code **

```
 $scope.submitForm = function() {
    // Posting data to php file
    $http({
      method  : 'POST',
      url     : 'http://localhost/youtubewebservice/checkOutt.php',
      data    : $scope.user, //forms user object
      headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
     })  
      .success(function(data) {
        if (data.errors) {
          // Showing errors.

          $scope.errorinputFName = data.errors.inputFName;
          $scope.errorinputLName = data.errors.inputLName;
          //$scope.errorMessage = data.errors.Message;
        } else {
          $scope.contactmessage = data.contactmessage;

        //data: {Name: $scope.Name, Email: $scope.Email, Message:  $scope.Message}
        }


      });  
    };
```